# Problem configuring Spring's MailSender for our SMTP-server (but GMail works)

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have some problems sending mails through SMTP using Spring's [MailSender](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/mail/MailSender.html) interface and the concrete implementation [JavaMailSenderImpl](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html). I'm able to send mail through GMail, but not through our company SMTP-server ([Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)).

### Correct configurations

To see that I have the correct configuration I used the excellent mail sender [ssmtp](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssmtp). It's a simple utility (which is able to emulate Sendmail) and is used solely for sending mail through SMTP.

Below are the two commands I used to send mail. The first one is for GMail and the second one for our company SMTP-server. Both mails arrived as they should and thus the configuration files that follow are correct.

```
$ ssmtp -C gmail-smtp.conf john.doe@gmail.com < gmail-message.txt 
$ ssmtp -C other-smtp.conf john.doe@thecompany.net < other-message.txt
```

The contents of the ssmtp configuration files and the message files are listed below. How the configuration file is structured can be seen at: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf:

*gmail-message.txt:*

```
To: john.doe@gmail.com
From: john.doe@gmail.com
Subject: Sent using the SMTP-server of GMail

Some content.
```

*gmail-smtp.conf:*

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=yes
AuthUser=john.doe@gmail.com
AuthPass=john_password
```

*other-message.txt:*

```
To: john.doe@thecompany.net
From: john.doe@thecompany.net
Subject: Sent using the SMTP-server of TheCompany

Some content.
```

*other-smtp.conf:*

```
# No username or password = no authentication
hostname=thecompany.net
mailhub=mail.thecompany.net:25
```

### MailSender configuration which works against GMail

I'm sucessful in sending mail through GMail using this Spring MailSender configuration:

```
...
<bean id="mailSender" class ="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" >
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="john.doe@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="john_password" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

### The problem (sending through the company SMTP-server)

With this MailSender configuration:

```
...
<bean id="mailSender" class ="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" >
    <property name="host" value="mail.thecompany.net" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
</bean>
...
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException; nested exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <rat>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:422)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:308)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:297)
... (The rest are methods I've created, which are irrelevant)
```

I **also** get *504 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname* if I remove *hostname=thecompany.net* from *other-smtp.conf* using **ssmtp**. I guess I have to provide the hostname somehow. My computers name is *rat* but it seems like it wants *thecompany.net*.

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the property "mail.smtp.localhost" with correct value (*thecompany.net*).

Answer (score 3):

To add to complete the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854493/problem-configuring-springs-mailsender-for-our-smtp-server-but-gmail-works/854603#854603) by matt b, the correct option of the javamail is `smtp.mail.localhost`

```
<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.localhost">thecompany.net</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Comment: Is it smtp.mail... or mail.smtp... ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you pass in the extra properties (hostname) you need to set with your SMTP server in the `javaMailProperties` property?

```
<bean id="mailSender" class ="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" >
    <property name="host" value="mail.thecompany.net" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <!-- addition: -->
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hostname">thecompany.net</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Not quite sure what the correct key name is for `hostname` in the JavaMail API.

Comment: Maybe. I have looked at the key names, thought I'm not sure I've seen them all, but I've found no hostname key. All keys seem to start with mail.something.

Answer (score 0):

I think its an address resolution problem in your case. make sure the mail server is accessible using the given name from the machine you've deployed this code on. if not just add an entry to your the hosts file.

Comment: I can send from the same machine using ssmtp. And if I can't connect I get another exception. So it's not an address resoultion problem.

Answer (score 0):

SMTPTransport mailFrom() sets the sender's address in the following order:

```
SMTPMessage.getEnvelopeFrom()
mail.smtp.from property
From: header in the message
System username using the InternetAddress.getLocalAddress() method
```

You just need to add property `from` in `javaMailProperies` to your email address